# How can I remove visible edge of solidified object (inverse hull outlining)

Tags: materials, solidify-modifier, toon-shading

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question and the title might be misleading so i'll show with images. I'm making a toon shader that uses a solidify modifier to apply an outline to the meshes it goes on to by flipping the normals of a material that has backface culling. However, this is prone to cause artifacts as seen here

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

Is there any way to fix this? by fix i mean a way for the outline to fill the areas that it dosent as shown in the images and if not then what is the best work around to making an outline with no artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this suggests an alternative approach

Backface culling for toon outlines has some rough edges that can't *easily* be fixed. If you don't need realtime performance and this project is only in Blender, I'd recommend Grease Pencil line-art.

Grease Pencil has a powerful option for Line Art, as in the screenshot below. This can either be per scene, per collection, or per object.

[image]

This creates new lines from the perspective of a Camera object. It adds a new LineArt object into your scene with a **lot** of modifiers to change up the style of the outline. This can be anything from a simple outline like your image to complex multi-modifier styles.

Sorry this doesn't resolve your specific use case, but it's one worth considering if your project allows it. If this doesn't help, there may be a way you can control the outline visibility through nodes rather than explicit backface culling. I'll try experiment!

[image]

Comment: this is def something i want to try however i cant seem to get the line art to appear on any object

Comment: There could be a few reasons for this. You'll need a Camera as the lines are projected from the Camera view's perspective (you can move a Camera to your current view with Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 0). The backface culling geometry could also be interfering with the new lines, so try disable this and see if anything changes.